# Using Cron job to activate a php script but it's not run completely

Tags: php, cron

I am using cronjob to activate a php script. Although when i do it manually from the browser, the script takes 3-4 seconds to load and it outputs result into the database.

When cron job does it, it seems that the script is unable to complete in the alloted time and the cronjob stops loading the script mid way, the cron works about 1/10 of the time, the rest 9/10 times it fails to complete the task. Is there a way i can ensure that the script is loaded completely each time the cron job activates it?

Script is simple completely php based. Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you run the script? are you using /usr/bin/php file.php or wget http://localhost/file.php?

Comment: do you mind positing your crontab entry and your php code?

Comment: We'll need to see the script to be of any help. It sounds like a permissions / file path error. Have you checked the error log?

Comment: Yes here is my cronjob entry - */15 * * * * php public_html/....................../script.php   (through cpanel)

Comment: the error log is empty, no issue in there, i have checked it. Sorry i am a bit hesitant to post code of script here as its large and proprietary by the company i work for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest implementing a lockfile (overrun protection) solution. Basically when your script kicks off it will do a check for a lockfile, and if the lockfile exists, the script can assume the previous incantation is still running, so it will halt execution. And when the script is complete it will remove the lockfile so subsequent runs can get passed the lockfile check and execute in their entirety.

A lock file usually contains the process id spawned by the script and usually located somewhere like /var/lock/my_script.lock.

You can google around for more info, but here is a [site](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/12/how-to-use-locks-in-php-cron-jobs-to-avoid-cron-overlaps/) with a lockfile example.